# How to add a column to an existing table in Loopback

Tags: node.js, model, loopbackjs

I have 2 models, Items and Policies. Both have already been deployed, with tables created in the DB (SQL).

I want to add a relationship between them: Item -> hasOne -> policy

I added this to Item.json:

```
"relations": {
    "policy": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Policy",
      "foreignKey": "policyId"
    }
```

And this to Policy.json

```
"relations": {
    "item": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Item",
      "foreignKey": "policyId"
    }
}
```

I thought that just by running the existing code, `autoregenerate` would notice the exiting differences, and add an extra column to the table. Instead, I get the error:

```
(node:216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Invalid column name 'policyId'.
    at handleError (C:\Users\user\Project\MyProject\node_modules\loopback-connector-mssql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:519:15)
```

Which I take to mean I've missed something. No extra column was created in the Item table, of course.

What do I need to do to initiate the column being added, or do I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a relation of `policy` in `item` then you should include relation on the `item` Model.

**Example** :

> We have two model `UserFollower` and `User` If we need to create `EndUser` relation in `UserFollower` then we changeto `UserFollower` with

```
"properties": {
        "followee": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "follower": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
  "relations": {
        "enduser_followee": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "EndUser",
            "foreignKey": "followee"
        }
    }
```

> As per your requirement just remove below code from `Policy.json`

```
"relations": {
    "item": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Item",
      "foreignKey": "policyId"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created them in both (see my question - both files were changed). Do I need to explicitly create a property on Item? Also, will it automatically associate your `UserFollower.followee` with `User.id`?